# GL posting after billing(vf01)

Tags: abap, accounting, sap-erp

I am new to SAP and was given a task to do enhancement on billing(VF01).

The enhancement was to generate General Ledger posting on a specific rules.How do i do it? should i use user exit? what are the exit name?and how do i do a General Ledger posting.please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is enough information to get you into trouble. These are the relevant user exits for VF01. You could always create your own z project in CMOD to do this.

```
EXIT_SAPLV60B_006
EXIT_SAPLV60B_002
EXIT_SAPLKBER_002
EXIT_SAPLKEAB_003
SD_CIN_LV60AU02
EXIT_SAPLMCS6_000
EXIT_SAPLMCS6_999
EXIT_SAPLMCS6_001
SDVFX010
IDOC_OUTPUT_INVOIC
COPA_CALL_CUSTOMER_EXIT_KEAB04
BADI_SD_DOCUMENTFLOW
```

If you provide more details on what you want to do you might get more help. Also, there are several ways to effect a GL posting depending on what your needing to accomplish.

Use a sandbox to try this out until you know what your doing as it is difficult to reverse these things.

Comment: Hi @apesa ,thanks for the response.im using ec 4.6 and what im trying to accomplish is a GL posting on tax ( ZNST & ZPST )

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand what you want to do but if you just want to create a tax posting corresponding to some invoice position (or the invoice head), you would usually modify the invoice condition scheme to add a tax condition. You can use the usual sap condition technique with condition tables and access sequences to get the new condition into the invoices.